# "No maps application installed , Please contact your car manufacturer" message is showing up in Automotive Android?

Tags: android, heremaps, android-automotive

As google android maps not currently present by default with Android Auto ,
below screen is displayed ,
[Android Auto home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FAwP.jpg)

Which is shown from MapsPlaceholderActivity
http://www.aospxref.com/android-11.0.0_r21/xref/packages/services/Car/car-maps-placeholder/src/com/android/car/mapsplaceholder/MapsPlaceholderActivity.java
I developed Maps application using HERE SDK, I am seeing same behavior even I install my Maps application .
Do I need to change anything at android framework level ? or any api or attribute that I missed from application level ?
I searched in opengrok , I couldn't able to find which app is calling MapsPlaceholderActivity and on what basis ?
Thankyou.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing  CarLauncherActivity , I understood, app with category as APP_MAPS
can replace MapsPlaceHolder .

```
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MAPS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Now ,map is displaying as expected .